# How to index the document with three letter month format?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Following is the document I have.

```
{
 "host": "172.31.183.9",
 "log_sequence": "47280",
 "log_date": "Nov 3 12:29:26.096"
}
```

I have tried the following date formats for mapping
a. dateOptionalTime
b. MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

but it is still showing mapper parsing exception. Can anybody suggest a way for the mapping format?

Comment: Have you tried `dd` instead of `d` for the month day?

Comment: That format works for me (`MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`). Are you sure you are posting the date according to that format or the mapping is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `Z` at the end of your date format, which expects a timezone offset/id, which is missing from your example.

So this pattern `MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS` should work.

Answer (score -2):

Elasticsearch official date format [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) says it support custom datetime format under [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Joda documentation for datetime mention

```
 M       month of year                month         July; Jul; 07
Month: 3 or over, use text, otherwise use number.
```

So you can refer this documentation to create a custom format for elasticsearch mappings and index the data accordingly.
I think you can figure out a way if you will play around with custom joda datetime formats.

Post the exact mappings if this helps